# Insert Text at Specified Position of A Large file

Tags: c#, xml, stream, large-files, xmlwriter

I have ***an extremely large file which I can't load into memory***.

Now I need to insert text at specified position.

***Before inserting:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Schema>
    <Line>1</Line>
    <Line>2</Line>
    ......
    <Line>999999</Line>
</Schema>
```

***After inserting:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Schema>
    <total>999999</total>
    <Line>1</Line>
    <Line>2</Line>
    ......
    <Line>999999</Line>
</Schema>
```

Can anyone provide with some suggestion to do such thing?

---

***Background:***

My real case is that I open a file stream for a new created file. Then I create an XmlWriter with this stream.

When each line comes, I writer corresponding  element into the file stream with XmlWriter.

However I need to put some information at the beginning of the file which I can only get after writing all lines, such as total lines.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you just reserve some space at the beginning, e.g. add `<total>********</total>` and then patch data in-place? Not very elegant, but fast and straightforward.

Comment: Are you sure the total has to be at the top? I don't believe the XML 1.0 spec defines element order as significant. Of course, the app that's consuming your xml might..

Comment: @AlexD: But I don't know how many spaces to reserve, otherwise there are additional spaces after patching.

Comment: @Blorgbeard: Actually the affected customers are my pain point. The customers have to read gigabytes to get the total value.

Comment: @FengZhao-MSFT You can add these extra spaces right after `<total>`.

Comment: @AlexD: Then the result will look like <total>  9999</total>. Not so elegant :)

Comment: @FengZhao-MSFT Oh, sorry, I meant after `</total>`. Still not perfect though :).

Comment: You could use `0` instead of spaces - so you might have `<total>000099999</total>`

Comment: Or you could add a `<!-- comment                         -->` instead of `<total>`, then replace with `<total>` and a similar comment with fewer spaces.

Comment: And of course, you could just process the file *again* after you've determined the total. Twice as slow, of course.

Comment: @Blorgbeard: Actually I have a lot of text to add, total line is just a sample. Can you share suggestion about how to process the file again?

Comment: I mean, once you've written the entire file to disk (without `<total>`, just keep that in memory), you could read the file you just wrote through a stream, and stream it out to a *new* file, inserting `<total>` at the top as you go. You don't have to load the entire file to memory at any point, but it costs you time and (temporary) disk-space.

Comment: But I don't have permission to create a new temp file on the disk. Is there a way to do that on the original file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to read the file as stream and output the stream to a new file with tag . There is no entire file loading problem.

Comment: Maybe that is the only solution. Thanks!